# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'GMSPlaceField'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
// Specify the place data types to return. 

guard let fields: 
GMSPlaceField = 
GMSPlaceField(rawValue: 
UInt(GMSPlaceField.all.rawValue)) else {return}
```

this code is from a running ios app from Swift 4.2

I have cloned the app from git
installed pods

issue with this one, I am not sure why

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a change in the Places SDK [beginning in 4.0.0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/migrate-nsoptions).

> Your implementation will break if you are using the `GMSPlaceField(rawValue:)` syntax as the constructor, which older versions of the SDK returned as an optional `GMSPlaceField?`.
>
> Version 4.0.0 and higher returns a non-optional `GMSPlaceField` value; any operations that are performed on the optional, such as conditional checks or force unwraps, will fail. In addition, you may now use array syntax to combine `GMSPlaceField`s

Since you no longer need to handle the optional, you can simply say

```swift
let fields = [GMSPlaceField.all]
```

Note the use of array syntax, as `GMSPlaceField` now uses `NS_OPTIONS`